# Accept only first request from a bulk of requests in NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a scenario where I will be receiving a hundred requests in less than 5 seconds and I only want to accept the first request and store that to the database (mongodb). Then the response to the users would be whether they were the ones accepted or not.

What approach or library do you recommend I use? I'm using NodeJS and Express. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Write a sequence of callbacks for each query into an array

2) When the very first request has finished its calculations - call all the callbacks

```
// routes/index.js
var requests = [];

router.get('/:order', function(req, res, next) {
    if (requests.length === 0) {
        var f = function() {
            res.json('first order complete');
        }
        requests.push( f );

        // Process first request
        setTimeout( function() {
            while (requests.length > 0) {
                requests.shift()();
            }
            requests = [];
        }, 10000);
    } else {
        var f = function() {
            res.json( req.params.order );
        }
        requests.push( f );
    }
});
```